# fail to access the first element of a JuMP.variable

Tags: julia

i have a code of Linear programming optimization, where i want to use it in another code, for the moment, i am struggling to fix a `BoundsError` in a function when i call a function from the code:

```
using JuMP
function scan_maker(A)
    m = JuMP.Model(solver=ClpSolver(PrimalTolerance=1e-3, DualTolerance=1e-3, InfeasibleReturn=1, PresolveType=1))
    # m = Model(solver=GurobiSolver())
    level = size(A, 2)
    v = zeros(Int, level)
    ub = zeros(Int, level)
    lb = zeros(Int, level)

    @variable(m, x[1:level])
    @constraint(m, con, A*x.>=0)

    function setc(c)
        for i = 1:size(A, 1)
            m.linconstr[i].lb = float(c[i])
        end
    end

    function scan(c::Channel)
        i = 1
        init = 1
        while i > 0
            if i >= init
                @objective(m, Max, x[i])
                res = JuMP.solve(m, suppress_warnings=true)
                if res==:Optimal || res==:Unbounded
                    ub[i] = round(Int, getvalue(x[i]))
                    setobjectivesense(m, :Min)
                    res = JuMP.solve(m, suppress_warnings=true)
                    @assert res==:Optimal || res==:Unbounded
                    lb[i] = round(Int, getvalue(x[i]))

                    v[i] = lb[i]
                    init += 1
                else
                    @assert res==:Infeasible
                    i -= 1
                    continue
                end
            elseif v[i] < ub[i]
                v[i] += 1
            else
                setupperbound(x[i], Inf)
                setlowerbound(x[i], -Inf)
                init -= 1
                i -= 1
                continue
            end

            if i >= level
                put!(c, v)
                continue
            else
                setupperbound(x[i], v[i])
                setlowerbound(x[i], v[i])
                i += 1
            end
        end
        close(c)
    end

    return setc, scan
end
```

now this code is working the way i want, but when i call the function `scan` from this code to another file in this function below:

```
function prob(na)
            @assert count(!iszero, ui2*na) == 0
            b = T0*na
            setc(-b)
            total = 0.0
            for x in Channel(scan)
                nab = vi2*x + b #the photon numbers for each item in the sum
                total += prod([c.^complex(n)/factorial(n) for (c, n) in zip(coef, nab)])
            end
            return abs(total*omega)^2
        end
```

and after that i call the function: `prob(200)` it shows me this error :
`BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{JuMP.Variable,1} at index [1]`
i know that the error raises in this expression of the `prob`function : `nab = vi2*x + b`and it is exactly in the variable `x` that was created in the first function that i put in this post: `@variable(m, x[1:level])`, but i'm stuck in how to fix this.
to check more the function where i'm having this problem you can check this link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/marouanehanhasse/Quantum_Relay/blob/master/src/QuantumRelay.jl)

Answer (score 0):

While your question is too long (far from MWE - minimal working example) and unclear let's assume that you want to work with array variables using JuMP. Here is a minimal example:

```
using JuMP
using GLPK
m = Model(with_optimizer(GLPK.Optimizer))
@variable(m, x[1:2] >= 0)
@constraint(m, x[1]+2x[2] <= 100)
@objective(m, Max, 3x[1]+7x[2])
optimize!(m)
```

Now let's get the result

```
julia> println(m)
Max 3 x[1] + 7 x[2]
Subject to
 x[1] + 2 x[2] <= 100.0
 x[1] >= 0.0
 x[2] >= 0.0

julia> value.(x)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
  0.0
 50.0
```

If you want to get the value of x[2] you simply write `value(x[2])`

Comment: it seems that you didn't understand my question so let me try to rephrase it let's suppose that we have the code that you wrote with a `Channel` in the answer and you are trying to call the variable `x` inside another function called `prob` as you can see in the post in another file but when you call it using `for`loop that you see i  the `prob`function then it shows you a `BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{JuMP.Variable,1} at index [1]`

Comment: You need rewrite your question and reduce your code to a minimal working example to get the answer otherwise I can just guess what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example